# Is there a way to insert element at certain position in unordered_map?

Tags: c++, insert, iterator, unordered-map

I am trying to insert element to a certain position in an unordered_map overwriting current pair at that position. I've tried the following code:

```
unordered_map<string, string>::iterator it = myMap.begin() + 256;
myMap.insert(it, newPair);
```

This is not working as it leaves an error. Can anyone please help? Thank you in beforehand.

Comment: You cannot overwrite a `key` in a map.  That would break that map.  Why do you need this?

Comment: Do you understand how a hash table works? Maybe look at that before using unordered_map.

Comment: I am implementing the LZW compression algorithm and I used unordered_map to save string-binary_code pair...

Comment: One of the interesting things about unordered maps is that they're unordered. That is, the things stored in them, aren't stored in a specific, guaranteed order. So, any logic depending on the order in which things are stored in an unordered map, is probably wrong.

Comment: The thing is I have 12bit codes in my algorithm so I have to limit the number of stored codes to 4096 inputs... for large files compression I have to overwrite the currently stored codes so the binary codes don't start to duplicate...

Comment: Almost sounds like a vector would be more appropriate.  Also note that `std::unordered_map` uses a forward iterator so `unordered_map<string, string>::iterator it = myMap.begin() + 256;` will not compile.

Comment: It is true yes, I guess I will just replace unordered_map with vector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert an object to certain position in the unordered_map. unordered_map uses hash implementation to achieve constant time for all common functions (insert, delete, find). The key in the unordered_map is always const you can't change it. About iterator for insert function, it is just a hint, this value may or may not be used by the container to optimize the operation.